# MongoDB $addToSet creates value as object

Tags: mongodb

On an Update, I'm trying to create a new array element or add to an existing array, which is how I interpreted $addToSet to work:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating

But what I get if "tag" doesn't exist is the value as an object, not an array:

"tag": {
     "0": "FreeShipping" 
  },

using

db.collection.update({ size : 10.5 }, {$addToSet : {tag : "FreeShipping"}} );

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried duplicating this and got the correct result please check below:

```
> use test
switched to db test
> db.test.insert({item:"test"});

> db.test.findOne();
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4ed69f9d1812423106a229ac"), "item" : "test" }

> db.test.update({item:"test"},{$addToSet:{tag:"FreeShipping"}});

> db.test.findOne();
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("4ed69f9d1812423106a229ac"),
    "item" : "test",
    "tag" : [
        "FreeShipping"
    ]
}
```

Can you please show your queries for adding it? Along with what version of MongoDB you're currently using as it seems to be working as expected (and as you're assuming).

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like this is a RockMongo bug. When I query with the shell I get the correct response. But RockMongo shows:  "tag": {
     "0": "FreeShipping" 
  },

Comment: More information about RockMongo displaying arrays as maps here: http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user/browse_thread/thread/58ec035fa1780101